# Python Threading Selenium

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

So I tried to run this code to run a webdriver 5 x at the same time, but is doesn't work. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

```js
def checkout():
  browser.get("https//:google.com")


for i in range(5)
browserThread = threading.Thread(target = checkout, args = (webdriver.Chrome()))
browserThread.start()
```

Comment: What is the error you receive ?

Comment: You sure that's the right site.

Comment: "https//:google.com" - it should be "https://", not "https//:"

Comment: TypeError: __main__.checkout() argument after * must be an iterable, not WebDriver

Comment: This the error I get

Comment: I see two issues here: 1.) `checkout` does not accept any arguments, yet you are trying to pass it one 2.) `args` must be a tuple.